# Can I execute rows returned by select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering if I can make a script to execute returned rows. I have 2 rows returned by select designed by me and it looks like

`alter table zamestnanci drop DF__zamestnan__datum__2E1BDC42 go sp_bindefault 'abc','zamestnanci.datum_pridania'`

I'm droping default and making binded default.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You would need to use dynamic sql for something like that. [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Output the result to text, not to grid, then copy + paste in query window

Comment: If you want to automate it, it is possible using `sp_executeSql` and a cursor.

Comment: If you want to automate it, wrap your select into a cursor, fetch 1 string at a time in a loop and just exec the fetched: exec(@sql)

Comment: You will need to get that "GO" out of there. It is not a t-sql statement, it is the default batch terminator in SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can run all of your statements in a single batch, and they are already correctly terminated with a semicolon, you could build a single SQL string and execute the whole thing at once.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT SomeColumn
                              FROM [Table]
                              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Of if you wanted to execute the statements one by one you could use a cursor:

```
DECLARE sqlCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  SomeStatement
    FROM    [Table];

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
OPEN sqlCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM sqlCursor INTO @sql;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
    FETCH NEXT FROM sqlCursor INTO @sql;
END
```

Comment: The first approach can easily fail on commands that should be "the only statement in the batch" because it has no batch separator and all is executed in 1 batch